# Disable Chrome "plugin not responding" message

Tags: debugging, gwt, google-chrome

It is quite annoying that this pop-up window appears every time I debug my GWT code using GWT dev-mode and Chrome's GWT Development plugin. Any ideas how to turn it off?

Comment: Following koma's answer i found this: http://saffer.posterous.com/gwt-debugging-stop-chrome-from-bugging-you-ab entry which also explains how to add `--disable-hang-monitor` to default HTTP launch handler.

Comment: I'm on Linux, sometimes forget there are other OS's out there :)

Comment: broken link: "Posterous Spaces is no longer available" :-(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
chromium-browser --disable-hang-monitor
```