# About Chrome's annoying behavior when I debug a Flash app

Tags: actionscript-3, debugging, google-chrome, popup

maybe this is kind of oftopic but.. its pissing me off.

When I debug a Flash app I'm developing, every 10-15 seconds when the app is on a breakpoint, a popup shows up saying that if I want to stop the plugin because seems to be unresponsive.

Is there any way to disable this behavior? or at least do it more sporadically?

Thanks.

Comment: It is a normal behavior of the browser and the flash player. If you are using the Flex, then in the project settings remove the HTML generation. Then it will be debugging directly in the flash player.

Comment: Cant do that, the app requires to be run on a web browser, otherwise I'd do that.

Comment: try this: http://anirudhsasikumar.net/blog/2011.05.17.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [Disable Chrome "plugin not responding" message](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9161926/disable-chrome-plugin-not-responding-message)